# Are built-in functions in R usually optimized?

Tags: function, r, optimization

I have some written code to compute the correlation coefficient in R. 
However, I just found out that the 'boot' package offers a corr() 
functions which does the same job. Are built-in functions in R
usually more efficient and faster than the equivalent ones we 
write from scratch?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume we're talking about Java here and Android. But how would we know unless you tag your question correctly? :P

Comment: @MetaCipher: Did I barely miss an edit or did you miss the `r` tag (admittedly, it's only one character)? And yeah, R is a programming language.

Comment: R is a programming language for statistical computing.

Comment: Even the title says "functions in R", not "functions in Java and Android"

Comment: The built-in function, if it drops down to C, should run 1-2 orders of magnitude faster, whether or not it's optimized, which I'm sure it is. Interpreted code is nearly always that much slower, so you would want to drop into the built-in functions whenever you can.

Comment: R is built from the S language and I don't know its relation to C.

Comment: R is a dialect of S; it is written in C and FORTRAN (and R).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a single specific answer to this question as it will vary wildly depending on the specific function you are asking about. Some functions in contributed packages are added as a convenience and are simply wrappers around base functions. Others are added to extend the base functionality or to address some other perceived deficit in the base functions. Some as you suggest are added to improve computation time or to become more efficient. And others are added because the authors of the contributing packages feel that the solutions in base R are simply wrong in some way.

In the case of `stats:::cor` and `boot:::corr`, it looks like the latter adds a weighting capability. It does not necessarily appear to be any faster:

```
> dat <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), ncol = 2)
> system.time(
+ cor(dat[, 1],dat[, 2])
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.01    0.00    0.02 
> system.time(
+ corr(dat)
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.11    0.00    0.11
```

Comment: I thought built-in functions might be a tad bit faster because if we write out the function and have to use it later, the computer needs to retrieve it in the memory. However if there is a built-in function,wouldn't executing that be more natural for the compiler. And I am dealing with large datasets where number computations can get up to 10^10 operations, so the time difference can add up.

Comment: Moreover, how do you access the source codes for this built-in functions from packages?

Comment: @GTyler you type the name of the function without parantheses at the end, for example princomp will give you the source code for that function.

Comment: What version of R and what computer do you have? When I run the functions in most recent version of R, I got: > system.time(cor(dat[, 1],dat[, 2]))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.04 
> system.time(corr(dat))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.12    0.03    0.16

Comment: @GTyler - you can type the function name without any parens or arguments to see the source code. i.e. `cor` or `corr`. Some methods are hidden and other are written in compiled code, so finding those takes a bit more work. Searching for `view function source` on SO seemed to turn up some relevant questions there. On your first question - I don't have enough insight into the internal workings of R to say anything remotely intelligent about that...sorry.

Comment: @GTyler - R 2.13, windows 7, 64 bit 8 gig ram machine. There's certainly some variability and error in the timing estimates. Look at `rbenchmark` package and specifically the `benchmark` function if you need more robust estimates.

Answer (score 3):

This more-less (i.e. not counting crappy code) boils down to a question whether certain procedure is implemented in R or as a C(++) or Fortran code -- if the function contains a call to `.Internal`, `.External`, `.C`, `.Fortran` or `.Call` it means this is this second case and probably it will work faster. Note that this is orthogonal to the question weather the function is from base R or a package.

However, you must always remember that efficiency is a relative thing and must be always perceived in context of the whole task and weighted with the programmer's effort necessary to speed something up. It is an equal nonsense to reduce execution time from 1s to 10ms, rewrte everything to use base just because *packages are evil* or invest few hours in optimizing function A while 90% of actual execution time hides in function B.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Chase's answer, I not only think that there is no single answer to this question but that this question is not that good. It is very unspecific. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for which questions to ask.
Furthermore, I have the feeling the OP is not aware of the `cor` function of base R, see `?cor`.

My answer: There are specialized functions that are extremely fast e.g., `rowSums` in comparison to `apply` with `sum`. On the other hand there are build in slownesses that could be avoided (if you are willing to invest some time to get down to the basics) but are build in due to design decisions. Radford Neal is arguing on this corner, see e.g. [one of his latest posts on the topic](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/slowing-down-matrix-multiplication-in-r/).

In sum, I guess the answer to this question nails down to what I think is the philosophy behind R: R is not the fastest horse in the race but definitely the one that achieves the most with the least code, if it is about data.

In general I think it is not that wrong to state, the more specialized a function is, the higher the possibility that it is very fast (and written in C or Fortran). The more general and abstract a function is the slower it generally is (compare the speeds of Hadley Wickham's `plyr` with the base `apply` family).

Answer (score 2):

One more point is that built-in R functions often have a lot of "wrapper" material that does error checking, rearranges data, etc..  For example, `lm` and `glm` each do a lot of stuff before handing over to `lm.fit` and `glm.fit` respectively for the actual number crunching. In your particular case, `cor` calls   `.Internal(cor(x, y, na.method, FALSE))` for Pearson correlations.  If (1) you really need speed and (2) you're willing to arrange the data appropriately yourself, and forgo the error-checking, you can sometimes save some time by calling the internal function yourself:

```
library(rbenchmark)
x <- y <- runif(1000)
benchmark(cor(x,y),.Internal(cor(x,y,4,FALSE)),replications=10000)
                            test replications elapsed relative user.self
1                      cor(x, y)        10000   1.131 5.004425     1.136
2 .Internal(cor(x, y, 4, FALSE))        10000   0.226 1.000000     0.224
```

But again this depends: we don't gain much at all when the matrices are large, as in the example above (so that the time spent error-checking relative to doing the computation is much larger) ...

```
x <- y <- rnorm(5e5)
benchmark(cor(x,y),.Internal(cor(x,y,4,FALSE)),replications=500)
                            test replications elapsed relative user.self
1                      cor(x, y)          500   5.402 1.013889     5.384
2 .Internal(cor(x, y, 4, FALSE))          500   5.328 1.000000     5.316
```